# Ввод однобайтового числа

Tags: c++

Как с помощью `cin` ввести однобайтовое целое число? Если вводить в char/unsigned char, то вводится символ, но не число. Можно ли как-нибудь настроить так, чтобы cin вводил в char число, а не символ? Знаю, что можно ввести в int и потом преобразовать в char, но интересует именно ввод в однобайтовое без создания временных int'ов

Comment: Хороший вопрос, неожиданный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Waylander123](/users/13501/waylander123), очевидно совсем не то, что Вы хотели, но чем-то похожее (конечно, на Си (а может на Си Вы это и так знали), но g++ воспринимает),  а вот `cin >>` побороть не удалось.

(В комментарий не поместилось, пришлось ответом).

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat tttx.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
  char x;

  scanf("%hhd", &x);
  cout << "C++: x=" << (x & 0xff) << '\n';
  printf ("C:   x=%d\n", x & 0xff);
}

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ tttx.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
12
C++: x=12
C:   x=12
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
234
C++: x=234
C:   x=234
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Обратите внимание на формат "%hhd" в `scanf()`. Модификатор **`hh`** указывает на 1 байт.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, через `std::istream` (`std::cin`) нельзя ввести `char` как число.

`std::istream` использует [`std::num_get::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get), у которой нет перегрузок для `char`.

Однако `std::num_get::get` использует `std::strtoll` для ввода чисел со знаком,
по этому чтение `int` из `std::cin` и преобразование его в `char` является вполне правильном решением.